# Android Studio 3.0 (Java 1.8 ) does not recognize java.util.Base64

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I am using Android Studio 3.0 and Jdk version is 1.8.0_152 .Java.util.Base64 is introduced in Java 1.8 . But still android studio does not recognize java.util.Base64 .Please help me to get out of this issue,

Comment: Could you post your code and gradle file?

Comment: compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    } I have included these lines in my gradle file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

> Android Studio 3.0 and later supports all Java 7 language features and a **subset** of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

**Old answer:**

Even though you have installed JDK 1.8 in your machine, Android Studio compiles the code compatible with Java1.7 by default.

You can use `android.util.Base64` instead.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: But in my android studio source compatibility and target compatibility is pointing to 1.8 only right ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Nabin Bhandari . It's woked for me

Answer (score 1):

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 26 or higher. Also, either set your `minSdkVersion` to 26 or higher, or arrange to only use `java.util.Base64` on Android 8.0+ devices, as that class was only introduced in that version of Android.